# Rmarkdown - embedded in a sentence

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I was wondering if it was possible to embed a `R markdown` result directly in a sentence as follows:

Let us imagine that this is my `R markdown` file

````
---
title: "R markdown is great"
author: "Giacomo"
date: "15 Oct 2015"
output: pdf_document
---

The mean number of `disp` is  

```{r}
mean(mtcars$disp) 
```
and the ...
````

So I get

[image]

Is it possible to produce something like

[image]

Comment: The mean number of \`disp\` is \`r mean(disp)\`.

Comment: wow I did not know we could do that ! amazing. Could you please answer that I can close the question. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Rmarkdown reference guide shows how this can be done: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf

The mean number of `disp` is `` `r mean(disp)` ``.